# Bootstrap responsive table - Won't scroll horizontaly in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/tukws1ao/

Video: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16876271/table-no-scroll.m4v

I have this HTML table at the bottom of the page that is bootstrap responsive and supposed to scroll horizontally on narrow screens. It works fine on all browsers, but not in IE - it doesn't scroll - scrollbars seem to be frozen (see video).

What makes it work: When I close the nav pane at the top, it starts scrolling -OR- if I delete a bunch of rows at the top of the table - it starts scrolling. Makes no sense! How do I make it scroll normally?

CODE:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr class="mu-white-xs mu-white-sm">
            <div class="panel-group" role="tablist">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="muItemTypesHeading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#muItemTypes" class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="muItemTypes">Select Item Type</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" id="muItemTypes" aria-labelledby="muItemTypesHeading" aria-expanded="true">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Item 1<span class="badge">9</span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Some other item 2<span class="badge">9</span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item active"><a href="#">AMS_TEST_ITEM<span class="badge">0</span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">CalendarEvents<span class="badge">9</span></a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">DublinCore<span class="badge">3273</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- end muItemTypes -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel group -->

          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->

      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 mu-hr-left" id="mu-item-types__attributes">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 mu-search">
            <label class="sr-only" for="mu-search-attributes">Search attributes</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control search" id="mu-search-attributes" placeholder="Search attributes..." maxlength="100">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search mu-search__search-ico"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove mu-search__reset-ico"></span></div>
          <!-- end col -->

        </div>
        <!-- end row -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr class="mu-spacer mu-white-xs mu-white-sm">
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">User</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->

          <div class="col-md-11 mu-pad-bottom mu-pad-top"><a class="small" href="" title="Hide Tabs"><small>Hide Tabs</small></a></div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-1 mu-pad-bottom mu-pad-top text-right"><a href="" title="Help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>
          <!-- end col -->

        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Internal Name</th>
                  <th>Display Name</th>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Required</th>
                  <th>Show</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Keyword</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Form Type</th>
                  <th>Min</th>
                  <th>Max</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="list">
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_STOR_STATUS</td>
                  <td>StorageStatus</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i100">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i100">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for=i101>Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i101">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i102">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i102">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i103">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i103">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i104">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i104">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i105">Type</label>
                    <select id="i105">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i106">Type</label>
                    <select id="i106">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_SZ</td>
                  <td>Size</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i107">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i107">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i108">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i108">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i109">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i109">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i110">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i110">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i111">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i111">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i112">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i112">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i113">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i113">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>100000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">ACLCODE</td>
                  <td>ACL</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i114">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i114">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i115">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i115">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i116">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i116">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i117">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i117">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i118">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i118">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i119">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i119">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i120">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i120">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>-88888</td>
                  <td>88888</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_STOR_STATUS</td>
                  <td>StorageStatus</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i100">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i100">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for=i101>Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i101">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i102">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i102">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i103">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i103">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i104">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i104">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i105">Type</label>
                    <select id="i105">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i106">Type</label>
                    <select id="i106">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_SZ</td>
                  <td>Size</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i107">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i107">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i108">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i108">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i109">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i109">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i110">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i110">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i111">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i111">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i112">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i112">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i113">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i113">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>100000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">ACLCODE</td>
                  <td>ACL</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i114">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i114">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i115">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i115">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i116">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i116">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i117">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i117">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i118">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i118">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i119">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i119">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i120">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i120">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>-88888</td>
                  <td>88888</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_STOR_STATUS</td>
                  <td>StorageStatus</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i100">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i100">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for=i101>Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i101">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i102">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i102">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i103">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i103">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i104">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i104">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i105">Type</label>
                    <select id="i105">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i106">Type</label>
                    <select id="i106">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">AMS_SZ</td>
                  <td>Size</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i107">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i107">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i108">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i108">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i109">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i109">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i110">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i110">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i111">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="i111">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i112">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i112">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i113">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i113">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>100000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="mu-searchable">ACLCODE</td>
                  <td>ACL</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i114">ID</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i114">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i115">Required</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i115">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i116">Show</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i116">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i117">Edit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i117">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i118">Keyword</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="i118">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i119">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i119">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="sr-only" for="i120">Keyword</label>
                    <select id="i120">
                      <option>String</option>
                      <option>Integer</option>
                      <option>Short</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>-88888</td>
                  <td>88888</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->

      </div>
      <!-- end col -->

    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->




  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="bootstrap-toolkit/bootstrap-toolkit.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine on my comp. IE 10, 9 and Edge.

Comment: Strange, as you can see in the vide my scrollbar is "frozen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might found another bug in Bootstrap indeed. While @captain's solution is best to follow as sooner or later you will hit a wall of data you can display on different devices (best practices with responsive tables) you can try this fix in the meanwhile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive {
        -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the @captain's solution. Did somebody post and delete? Your solution fixed the issue. However, I might have to forget about using a table here and use divs instead...

Comment: Tables are for tabular data so i don't think this should be solved with divs, but - it's a challenge to accommodate large amount of tabular data on all devices, Captain sent something like this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/. Cheers, glad it helped.